# Progressbar in ListBox shows wrong values

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, progress-bar

I have a ListBox with lot of items, those items include horizontal PorgressBar. Items are databound to ObservableCollection which are created from IQueryable. The viewmodel contains the Max value and current value which are displayed correctly on TextBlock but not in progressbar. When I scroll the list the progressbars show random progress. Is there any cache mechanism that may cause the progress bar not updating? Or maybe is it connected with virtualization. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

even though your collection contains all the list items, the binding will happen only when you scroll down. i.e. when you scroll down listBox new item will be created dynamically and will be bound to ListBox. The number of items bound initially will depend on Height of ListBox. And as the progress bar shows the items bound to Listbox it shows random progress. Will let you know the solution/work-around in some time.

Comment: I know, when I'm scrolling down new ListBox Items are created and invisible ones are destroyed. But the value and max value of progressbar are databound to the models in observablecollection. So why doesn't it show the right progress? Textblock values are correct, and the same properties I display in TextBlock are databound to progressbar.

Comment: For now I chenegd VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode to "Standard" instead of "Recycle" and it seems to work now, but I don't know if it would impact performance.